# Is there a way to spoof the date on a browser visit with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, phantomjs

I want to use PhantomJS to run a test suite that requires visiting pages which log statistics based on the current date.

But I would like to be able to log test data point for dates in the past as well – the problem is, the code that logs the stats currently uses the user's current timestamp.

Is there any way to "spoof" the "current date" when opening a page using PhantomJS (or a similar tool)?

Comment: No.  The date comes from the operating system and obviously your browser has no control over that.  Can you not make it use a variable for the date and then you can simply override that value when testing?

Comment: Question doesn't seem right... you are asking about the environment and not about the test code itself

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- [set the system time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151547/linux-set-date-through-command-line) - you should run this in a virtual machine, better not mess with your own machine's system time
- use a tool that overrides the time function in your language (e.g. [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) in Ruby, or [for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922322/157328)); or if not possible, create a new time function that can return values injected by the test, and call this instead of calling the system time function